# A bump on the tire. Is it serious?

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

I have recently discovered a bump on a tire of my 2018 Camry SE. I have had this baby for a month shy of a full year now. The bump may have come from curb rash or a pothole. I am putting up a picture. Is this serious? Should I have the tire replaced/repaired?

The tire pressure is slightly higher than the rest of the tires (by 1 or 2).

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bulge in the tire means the tire has lost integrity. Given enough time, the bulge will get bigger as more integrity is lost until it gets to the point where it will completely fail. The only cure for this is to replace the tire. There is no repair for this tire.

Comment: Thank you! This might be a dumb question, but does it mean the this is an impact break for sure?

Comment: @EddieKal - Not a dumb question. No, it *might not be* from an impact. There does appear to be a crease on the sidewall, though, which would indicate there was more than likely an impact.

Answer (score 2):

the tire is separating. The bulge is where the tire is coming apart. it will get bigger in time. there is no way to fix it. if you hit something that puts a hole in that bulge it will loose air from the hole. Get a new or used tire as soon as possible....